# output array to template

Tags: forms, templates, silverstripe

I'm trying to add a custom form with a series of radio buttons. I need to output a list into the template that I can loop over. but when I run this code nothing gets output. if I add text inside my loop it's only output once.

in my page_controller class

```
public function outputArray($array){
    $dl = DataList::create("DataObject");

    foreach ($array as $it) {
        $do = new DataObject();
        $do->Value = $it;
        $do->write();
        $dl->push($do);
    }

    return $dl;
}

public function NumList(){return $this->outputArray(array("0","1","2","3","4","5"));}
```

in my template

```
<% loop NumList() %>
    $Value
<% end_loop %>
```

Comment: Why do you want to output a list into the template to loop over? What are you trying to do? I think there may be a better way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to create a form to rate things. so each rate would be a seperate radio button that are only different by their value. So if I can use a loop then the number of rating options could be arbitrary. I agree my solution doesn't feel like the best way, but in my research it seems like this is the best option.

Comment: If you are creating the form in the controller you can create the radio buttons in the controller too. Are you creating the form in controller or in template with just html code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. That is how I would write it:

```
public function outputArray($array)
{
    $dl = new ArrayList();

    foreach ($array as $it) {
        $dl->add(array('Value' => $it));
    }

    return $dl;
}
```

and in the SilverStripe Template:

```
<% loop $NumList %>
    $Value
<% end_loop %>
```

If you use the Form class of SilverStripe you should have a look at this: http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SelectionGroup.html
This would enable you to just set a key->value array on a object and get the radio buttons rendered by SilverStripe.